# Make cells of ListView wrap content

Tags: android, listview, layout

I am making a chat application and I'm running into a bit of an issue.

[image]

This is how my chat activity looks like and here is the code:

chat.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
      android:id="@+id/lvMessageHistory"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="0px"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etMessage"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

      <Button 
          android:id="@+id/btnSend"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="4"
          android:text="@string/send"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

chat_cell.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/chatMessageLayout"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="right">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvUser"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/send"
       android:textStyle="bold"/>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tvTime"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   </LinearLayout>     
</LinearLayout>
```

Now what I want is for the bubbles to be smaller, i.e. just to wrap the text inside of them, while at the same time having the full width to set their gravity to left or right based on the sender.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I am setting up the background on chatMessageLayout programatically.

```
LinearLayout chatMessageLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chatMessageLayout);    
if (position % 2 == 0) {
   chatMessageLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_right);
} else {
   chatMessageLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_left);
}
```

I am using a 9 patch image.

Comment: Please copy the code where you set the background. Also let us know if you're using a 9 patch image. Thanks.

Comment: I added all these details.

Comment: Thanks. To exclude it's a problem of the 9 patch, just put a color as background of the layout. Please also copy the code where you change the gravity.

Comment: I don't change the gravity yet.